# Slice sets of columns in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, slice, broadcast, stride

Consider a `numpy array` as such:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1], [2, 3, 2, 2, 2], [0, 3, 3, 2, 2]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 3, 3, 2, 2]])
```

And an `array` which contains couples of column indexes to slice (a specific column can appear in multiple couples):

```
b = [[0,1], [0,3], [1,4]]
```

How can I slice/broadcast/stride `a` using `b` to get a result as such:

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [0, 3]],

       [[1, 0],
        [2, 2],
        [0, 2]],

       [[2, 1],
        [3, 2],
        [3, 2]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `b` as column indices to subset the array and then transpose the result:

```
a[:, b].swapaxes(0, 1)

# array([[[1, 2],
#         [2, 3],
#         [0, 3]],
#        [[1, 0],
#         [2, 2],
#         [0, 2]],
#        [[2, 1],
#         [3, 2],
#         [3, 2]]])
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks